# string.ToLower() method in C# doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, string

When I call this method for strings which begin with `I` it returns something like that: `ı..` because of that I cannot compare `string.ToLower().StartsWith("i")`.

What to do?

Comment: would you pls post some code that raises this error..

Comment: We'd need to see some code to help you debug this

Comment: Are you sure the character is the english letter I ?

Comment: yes it is.ok wait for minute,i will add the code here

Comment: in unicode there are some charachters looking similar to an "i" while not being one... I suspect you don't have an "i" in that string...

Comment: could that be the Turkish "dot-less" i ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

Comment: no it comes from "System.Drawing.Internal" it is english based.and there is couldnt be Turkish letters

Comment: Please search for "the Turkey test"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ToLowerInvariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolowerinvariant.aspx) instead.